# Canvas.drawBitmap() and freeing up memory

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I have a `ListView` and the items in the list are custom `View`s. The `View` class has a field

```
private Bitmap bitmap;
```

and the `onDraw` method of the `View` uses

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

The trouble is that I am geting `OutOfMemoryError`s. What I want to do is free up the memory associated with the `Bitmap` when the item scrolls off the screen. I thought I could write `bitmap = null` to allow the garbage collector to take the `Bitmap`, but I am worried that `canvas.drawBitmap` might mean that this doesn't work. Does `canvas.drawBitmap` hold onto a reference to the `Bitmap`? Or does the call `canvas.drawBitmap` mean that the `Canvas` object itself has as much memory as the `Bitmap`? The trouble is I don't really understand what a `Canvas` is, and what the various `draw` calls actually do. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you're displaying large amounts of bitmap data in your app, you're
>   likely to run into OutOfMemoryError errors. The recycle() method
>   allows an app to reclaim memory as soon as possible.

However if you call recycle() and later attempt to draw the bitmap, you will get the error: "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap".

But you need to do some extensive reading of  [the android's site training on Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) as you will have different strategies according to the API you use.

Take a look at the whole guide of [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) . It contains all you can need for keeping down the memory usage:

- [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
- [Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)
- [Caching Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)
- [Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) - which answered your
  bitmap memory reclaim
- [Displaying Bitmaps in Your UI](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html)

If you follow those guidelines you should be able to get rid of your memory leaks and improve user experience.

> Does canvas.drawBitmap hold onto a reference to the Bitmap? Or does the call canvas.drawBitmap mean that the Canvas object itself has as much memory as the Bitmap?

The canvas holds a reference to the bitmap as you phrased it.

A Canvas works for you as a pretense, or interface, to the actual surface upon which your graphics will be drawn — it holds all of your "draw" calls. Via the Canvas, your **drawing is actually performed upon an underlying Bitmap**, which is placed into the window. The Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap.